# Multiple github packages in Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, multiple-repositories

I have two `github pacakges` named `XXX/AAA` and `YYY/BBB` (same `OWNER` but different `repository`).
Now, when I try to add them into my project, gradle always seem to use the 1st repository.

```
repositories {
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
maven {
    url "https://maven.pkg.github.com/XXX/AAA"
    credentials {
        username = USERNAME
        password = PWD
    }
}
maven {
    url "https://maven.pkg.github.com/XXX/BBB"
    credentials {
        username = USERNAME
        password = PWD
    }
}}
```

And `com.example` in implementation is also same.

```
dependencies {    
//  implementation 'com.example:package'  
// AAA
implementation("YYY:AAA:${a_version}")
// BBB
implementation("YYY:BBB:${b_version}")
}
```

and I receive the following error while syncing

```
Could not HEAD 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/XXX/AAA/YYY/BBB/0.1/BBB-0.1.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

As we can clearly see, gradle uses the wrong repository(AAA instead of BBB)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare these repositories as [exclusive](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#declaring_content_exclusively_found_in_one_repository) for the respectful dependencies:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    exclusiveContent {
        forRepository {
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/XXX/AAA'
                credentials {
                    username = "USERNAME"
                    password = "PWD"
                }
            }
        }
        filter {
            includeModule("YYY", "AAA")
        }
    }
    exclusiveContent {
        forRepository {
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/XXX/BBB'
                credentials {
                    username = "USERNAME"
                    password = "PWD"
                }
            }
        }
        filter {
            includeModule("YYY", "BBB")
        }
    }
}
```